# Error enabling Liberty profile on WAS ND 8.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I have an installation of WAS ND 8.5.5.9 and I would like to use the Liberty profile as I am already developing in Eclipse using Liberty.  However, I cannot seem to locate instructions for enabling Liberty within WAS ND.

I see in the admin console (Servers > Server Types > Liberty Profile Servers) the ability to create Liberty servers.  However, I am unable to get anything working because it does not seem to be fully enabled within WAS itself.

Could someone please point me to instructions on how to install Liberty so that it can be managed within WAS ND admin console?

Answer (score 4):

The best place to start would be here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_inst_top.html?pos=2

From your post you have installed WebSphere Application Server Traditional, and created a deployment manager profile. That does not enable Liberty. You need to install WebSphere Liberty separately. The instructions are in the Knowledge Center above, but you can also get it from http://wasdev.net.

One thing to note we do not recommend managing Liberty from the deployment manager cell. Managing Liberty from a deployment manager just gives you access to view the logs and start/stop the server, it doesn't provide any real system admin capability beyond that. You are better off using Liberty Collectives and the Admin Center.